# WPF binding issues while using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, mvvm, command

Time for my first question :)

I have the following:

```
public class BuilderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private double _contentScale = 1.0;

    public double ContentScale
    {
        get { return _contentScale; }
        set
        {
            _contentScale = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ContentScale");
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 

    #region Commands

    bool CanZoomIn() { return true; }
    void ZoomInExecute()
    {
        ContentScale += 1.0;
    }

    public ICommand ZoomIn { get { return new RelayCommand(ZoomInExecute, CanZoomIn); } }

    #endregion
}
```

And the corresponding view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PS_IDE.FormBuilder.View.Builder"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PS_IDE.FormBuilder.ViewModel">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:BuilderViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentScale}" Width="100" />

</UserControl>
```

I'm trying to have the ZoomIn command in BuilderViewModel update the text box value in it's view.  The command is being fired from another user control, UIBuilder, which includes Builder.  If I debug and fire the command from UIBuilder, I can see it updating ContentScale properly.

However, my text box value does not get updated (it only says "1", which is the initial value of ContentScale).

I know I'm missing something and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:  Added the control that is firing the command**

```
<UserControl x:Class="PS_IDE.FormBuilder.UIBuilder"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PS_IDE.FormBuilder"
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:PS_IDE.FormBuilder.ViewModel"
         xmlns:View="clr-namespace:PS_IDE.FormBuilder.View" mc:Ignorable="d">  
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:BuilderViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

        ....

        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Height="24" Width="24" ToolTip="Zoom In" Command="{Binding ZoomIn}">
                    <Image Source="Images/ZoomIn.png" Height="16"/>
                </Button>

                ....

            </ToolBar>
       </ToolBarTray>
       <View:Builder x:Name="builder" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you show us the control which fires the `ZoomIn` command?

Comment: I added it to the end of the original post :)

Comment: Just for the hell of it, does it work if you do ContentScale = ContenScale + 1.0; instead of ContentScale += 1.0; ? Are you sure you're using the same instance of the BuilderViewModel as your datacontext for both views?

Comment: Nope, same issue.  I can see it updating in the debugger but the binding is still not being updated.

Comment: Do you get any type of binding error message in the output window?

Comment: Nope.  Issues has been resolved below.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the setting **in both view**:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:BuilderViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

you are basically **creating two viewmodels**, one for each view. So when your Command updates the property it does it on one of the viewmodel but your textbox is bound to a different viewmodel.

To resolve it **remove** the `DataContext` setting from the `Builder.xaml`

Additionally you need to pass your `DataContext` to your `Builder` control (with this both view will share the same viewmodel).

So modify your UIBuilder.xaml:

```
<View:Builder x:Name="builder" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes total sense.  I knew I was missing something.  All my problems have been solved, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Mode TwoWay in your binding

```
 Text ="{Binding ElementName=BuilderViewModel,
         Path=ContentScale,
         Mode=TwoWay,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Nota : use observable collection in order to send notify

Comment: Mode TwoWay is the default in WPF for TextBox.Text, and anyway OP has the problem with the other direction, when the changes in the viewmodel are not reflected in the view.

Comment: I've already tried TwoWay.  I do only need it to go one way, in that when the ViewModel is updated, the View reflects that.

Comment: add observable collection in order to send notification to view